# xcode, storyboard, order of actions

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I inherited a swift project that I need to change: I need to add a line in the list of settings, with a segue to a new ViewController.

Is this the correct order of actions:

- first build the new ViewController (can I copy-paste from another ViewController?)
- then add a new line in the "settings" list ( can I copy-paste another listItem?)
- then add a segue from the new listItem to the new ViewController ( any hint on how to do it is welcomed...)

or

- can I copy-paste a listItem and it will also copy its segue and its activity?

what is the correct way?

( I did the same change in android project, changing android.activity.xml is much more easier than using xcode.storyboard.userInterace )

[image: storyboard screenshot]

Comment: it will not copy the segue but uses all attributes, also sometimes uses same actions if any but not segue, Also once you are fimiliar to storyboard, You will use words with vice versa  :D

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use separate .xib for the new ViewController (IMO it will be much easier and harder to mess things up)

actions:

- add new line in the settings (with it's own action). Without any code it's hard to say if you can copy any of the previous but I would assume you can (if it's in the storyboard just check the outlets of the copied and remove them)
- Create new ViewController with .xib file (File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class (subclass of: `UIViewController`, make sure `also create XIB file` is checked)
- In the action of the item (assuming the previous ViewController is embedded in NavigationController)

```
        let myNewFancyViewController = FancyViewController()
        show(myNewFancyViewController, sender: self)
```

- Modify the new view controller

EDIT:
Since you added image of the storyboard:
`Settings` looks like to use static table view cells, it should be easy to copy one of them and add it where needed. Copying ViewController is also possible just make sure that all outlets (views/actions) are removed. Last step is just to `option` + drag from the **cell** that you created and select `show` (You can add `identifier` to the segue if you want to pass data between the view controllers)

NOTE: after copying the new view controller seems to remove all the existing outlets, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Larme only if the name is incorect